# Problem when displaying integer arithmetic with a random number in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, functional-programming

Let's say I want to generate a random number in Haskell. To do so, I'll make use of

```
randomRIO (0, 10)
```

that generates a number between 0 and 10 for me. It's type is

```
randomRIO (0,10) :: (Random a, Num a) => IO a
```

Now, let's say I assign its result to a value `k`. It's type is `IO Integer`.

Trying to do usual arithmetic stuff such as `k + 2` will yield the following result in Ghci:

```
<interactive>:1:3:
    No instance for (Num (IO Integer))
      arising from the literal `2'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (IO Integer))
    In the second argument of `(+)', namely `2'
    In the expression: k + 2
    In an equation for `it': it = k + 2
```

The problem also happens when trying asking Ghci about

```
[randomRIO (0, 10) | x <- [0..10]]
```

The error message is a bit cryptic, how can I make use of random numbers in Haskell?

Comment: Really, this question is "how do I use IO in Haskell?".  The fact that you're doing random numbers is almost unrelated to the problem you're having.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A value of type `IO Integer` is not an integer. It's an action that, when performed, will return an integer. The distinction is important. The only way to perform `IO` actions is to hook them up to `main`, or type them into GHCi.

So `randomRIO (0, 10)` is an action, that when performed, returns a random number between `0` and `10`. Note that this is *not* a function, as a function must always return the same result given the same input, although we sometimes call this an *impure function*.

So the question is, how do you take an action returning an integer and make an action returning an integer plus two? Easy, you can use `fmap` to combine an action and a pure function transforming its result into a new action.

```
fmap (+2) $ randomRIO (0, 10)
```

`Control.Monad` contains many useful functions for building new actions out of other actions. For your second example, we can use `replicateM`, which creates an action that, when performed, runs the original action multiple times, collecting the results into a list:

```
replicateM 10 $ randomRIO (0, 10)
```

You can also obtain similar results manually using `do`-notation.

For more information, you should read up on monads, for example in [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Comment: This is all sensible, but I wonder if it might get even easier if we had an `instance Num n => Num (IO n)` lifting all the operations pointwise, and similarly for other `Applicative` functors which don't have an intrinsic `Num`-like quality. This lifting has certainly been used to great effect for streams.

Comment: @pigworker: The problem is that it would violate laws all over the place. For example `x + x` would be quite different from `2 * x` when `x = randomRIO (0, 10)`. It would also violate the commutativity of `+`, and many other identities.

Comment: That's a fair point. On the other hand, the IO type makes it perfectly clear that it's unreasonable to expect those laws.

Comment: @pigworker: Well, that's not all. You'd also have trouble implementing the superclasses `Eq` and `Show`. Also, functions which assume those identities hold, for example `^`, would be useless with those types. It's basically just a way of trading some inconvenience at coding/compile time for possible bugs at run time.

Comment: True, although having `Eq` and `Show` as superclasses for `Num` is a bigger mistake. Meanwhile, how many of these laws hold for the IEEE floating point instances of `Num`? You already have to pay attention to the type to know what the real deal is. (I agree with you. I'd rather applicative programming in monads was notationally cheaper and that `Num` was more disciplined.)

Comment: Yes, IEEE break most of the laws you expect to hold.  I think the only  bad thing about `Num (IO n)` is that it would encourage people to do things they shouldn't. :)

Answer (score 4):

You would best be served by working through a resource like [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/). A very relevant section is [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#randomness).

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned GHCi, note that you can also execute IO actions in the prompt and bind the value from the action to a name by using `<-`.

```
a <- randomRIO (0, 10)
a + 2
```

However, I suggest you read through the tutorial that Anthony and hammar linked. It'll explain the above syntax (and other ways to manipulate monadic values) in more detail.

Comment: Ah! That's what I was actually looking for!

Comment: How to accomplish the same effect with lists? map (\x -> x <- randomRIO (0,10)) [1..10] doesn't seem to work.

Comment: With a list your type is `[IO Integer]` which is generalized as `[m a]`. What you want is `m [a]` (in your case `IO [Integer]`).
That is where you can use `sequence` function. 
This should work for you: `sequence [randomRIO (0, 10) | x <- [0..10]]`

Comment: @devoured use `mapM` from `Control.Monad` and don't use bind, i.e.  `mapM (\x -> randomRIO (0,x)) [1..100]`  or more what it looks like you were just trying to do: `mapM (const $ randomRIO (0,10)) [0..10]` which is the same as `replicateM 10 (randomRIO (0,10))`

Comment: @dev Try `xs <- sequence $ map (\x -> randomRIO (0,10)) [1..10]` or `xs <- sequence $ replicate 10 $ randomRIO (0,10)`.